# Counting number of rows equal to the rows in another matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, count

I have the next problem. I have a matrix A whose rows are all possible permutations of the sequence `seq(1:D)`. I have other D matrixes whose rows are also permutations. I want to generate a matrix with dimension `D!xD` whose `[i,j]` component is the number of rows identical to the `j-th` row of A in the `i-th` matrix.
A litle example:

```
A= [1,2,3
    1,3,2
    2,1,3
    2,3,1
    3,1,2
    3,2,1]   #Matrix of all posible permutations
```

and

```
B= [1,2,3
    1,2,3
    3,2,1] #One of my D matrixes
```

and

```
C=[2,1,3
   1,2,3
   2,3,1]. #Another of my matrixes
```

The output I´m looking for is

```
count= [2,1
        0,0
        0,1
        0,1
        0,0
        1,0].
```

Could you help me? I don't want to use a loop because I have enough in my code and this is supposed to be into a loop.

Thank you so much-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data:**

```
A <- matrix( c(1,2,3,1,3,2,2,1,3,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,2,1), nrow = 6, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
B <- matrix( c( 1,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,1), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
C <- matrix( c(2,1,3,1,2,3,2,3,1), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

**Code:** combine the columns into one number string per row, and compare the vector of A with B and C.

```
A <- apply(A, 1, paste0, collapse = "_")
B <- apply(B, 1, paste0, collapse = "_")
C <- apply(C, 1, paste0, collapse = "_")

sapply( list(B,C), function(x) {
  sapply( A, function(y) sum(x %in% y))
})
```

**Output:**

```
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    1
# [2,]    0    0
# [3,]    0    1
# [4,]    0    1
# [5,]    0    0
# [6,]    1    0
```

Comment: probably safer to collapse with a separator like `_` or `.` I think it was the position of the match rather than a count that was requested.

Comment: I'm afraid this solution has a problem. Imagine one row of `A` starts with `11, 2, 3, ...`. Then this row will become `1123...`, the same if the row were ´1, 12, 3, ...`. I think that's why @42 proposes a separator.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I used it into a code and it decreased the time from 896.04 sec to 196.23, which is awsome beacause I´ll have to use this code a really big amount of times.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, a bit similar to @Sathish's one:

```
A <- matrix( c(1,2,3,1,3,2,2,1,3,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,2,1), nrow = 6, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
B <- matrix( c( 1,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,1), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
C <- matrix( c(2,1,3,1,2,3,2,3,1), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)

# count rows of a matrix M equal to a vector vect
rowsEqualToVector <- function(vect, M){
  sum(apply(M, 1, function(matRow) identical(vect, matRow)))
}

# apply the previous function to each row of a matrix A
sameRows <- function(A,M){
  apply(A, 1, function(row) rowsEqualToVector(row, M))
}

# map the previous function to a list of matrices
sapply(list(B,C), function(M) sameRows(A,M))
```

Output:

```
> sapply(list(B,C), function(M) sameRows(A,M))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    1
[4,]    0    1
[5,]    0    0
[6,]    1    0
```

Comment: I'm afraid `identical` could cause a problem when the matrices have different dimension names.  In this case one should replace `identical(vect, matRow)` with `all(vect==matRow)`.